# Broadcast receiver takes time to receive the broadcast

Tags: android

```
public synchronized void startAppOnScheduleTime(final int time)
    {
      //create new calendar instance for your start time
       final Calendar startTime= Calendar.getInstance();

     //set the time to USER SPECIFIED start time
       startTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, time / 100);
       startTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, time % 100);
       startTime.set(Calendar.SECOND, 1); // Add 1 second of additional delay

       /*System.out.println(" time set is  "+startTime.getTime().toString());

       System.out.println(" time set is  "+Long.toString(startTime.getTimeInMillis()));
       Date date = new Date(startTime.getTimeInMillis());
       SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss:SSS");
       String dateFormatted = formatter.format(date);*/

       if (startTime.getTimeInMillis() - Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() <= 0)
       {
           // Time has already past, schedule for next day
           startTime.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
       }
       try
       {
             AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

             //create a pending intent to be called at startTime
              Intent myIntent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), StartApplicationReceiver.class);
             PendingIntent startPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_RECEIVER_FOREGROUND), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

             //schedule time for pending intent, and set the interval to day so that this event will repeat at the selected time every day
             am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, startTime.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, startPI);
        }
       catch(Exception ex)
       {
           ex.printStackTrace();
       }

    }

//my receiver

public class StartApplicationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        //on Receive of Start Application Receiver
        try
        {

                //here iam starting an application with the package name 
            }

         } 
        catch (Exception e) 
         { 
            //You don't have the application installed
            e.printStackTrace();
         }

    }

}
```

I am able to start an application but it starts after two minutes of specified start time and also i have added highest priority for this broadcast in the manifest.

have a look at my manifest

```
<receiver android:name="packagename.StartApplicationReceiver"
            android:priority="999"></receiver>
```

Comment: <receiver android:name="packagename.StartApplicationReceiver"
            android:priority="999"></receiver>

Comment: Are you using emulator?

Comment: no Iam not using an emulator.

Comment: Why are you doing `startTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, time / 100);
       startTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, time % 100);`. Shouldn't you use `time/60` and `time%60`?

Comment: Iam doing this because Iam getting time as Int like say 820 for(8:20) and dividing by 100 I set Hour of the day as 8 and when time 820%100 then iam getting minutes as 20